# How to add horizontal delimeter in NewForm.aspx?

Tags: css, custom-form

I'm trying to add "Optional" section and horizontal delimeter in SharePoint form(like on screenshot). 
[image]
I created copy CustomNewFrom in SharePoint Designer, added

```
<style type="text/css">
tr.bordered {
    border-bottom: 5px solid red;
}
</style>
```

and set tr class=bordered:

```
                    <tr class="bordered">
                    <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
                        <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
                            <nobr>Requester name</nobr></H3>
                    </td>
                    <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
                        <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff2{$Pos}" ControlMode="New" FieldName="Requester_x0020_name" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff2',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Requester_x0020_name')}"/>
                        <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff2description{$Pos}" FieldName="Requester_x0020_name" ControlMode="New"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
                        <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
                            <nobr>OPTIONAL:</nobr></H3>
                    </td>
                    <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

but nothing happens. What should I do to apply this style?

[image]

update: I can add two `<hr/>` tags, but in this case I have two separators, that is not cool(

```
             <tr>
                <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
                                        <hr/>
                    <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
                        <nobr><b>OPTIONAL:</b></nobr></H3>
                </td>
                <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
                                        <hr/>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Edit Newform as advanced mode .
- From the above ribbon > Insert new form > cutom list form .
  [image]
- the list fields now shown within table
- add a new row > merge it > and from the Above ribbon > Check HTML Control > Add Horizontal line at the new row

[image]

> Don't forget to remove old WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart

Comment: Hi Joun! But when I insert hr between <tr> tags, it adds on the top of the page, but now between table section. Where I need to insert it?

Comment: Hi, Gennady! Are you already added a custom list form ? where you added the <tr>?

Comment: Insert NewForm is grayed-out for me, I'm trying to play with existing copy (MyCustomNewForm.aspx) - I see <tr> and <td> tags, but how to merge them(I updated my question a little)

Comment: try to Merge the row from the above ribbon

Comment: Ahh, colspan="2".. Thank You very much Joun!

Comment: You are welcome and great news to work

Answer (score 2):

No need to change the HTML

You can target the TDs in TR (3rd row) with the CSS selector:

```
.ms-formtable tr:nth-child(3) td {
    border-bottom:2px solid red;
}
```

The TR does not accept border styles